# Unable to access the virtual machine configuration (vmware automation) while cloning from template - Ansible version 2.13

Tags: ansible, vmware-vsphere

I'm wondering whether any of you have encounter similar issue.
I have 2 Ansible machines. One is running on Centos 7, version 2.9.27 (with python 2.7.5) and second on Ubuntu 22 with Ansible 2.13

Using Centos as my deployment machine I can clone and configure VM's from template without any issues. I'm using ansible collection community.vmware modulesby the way

While trying to deploy VM from template using Ansible 2.13 (same playbook code as for Centos), I'm getting really weird error:

```
fatal: [XXX-016 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create a virtual machine : Unable to access the virtual machine configuration: Unable to access file [host-004-local-sas] Ubuntu22_04_x64-template/Ubuntu22_04_x64-template.vmx"}
```

I installed community.vmware package with all prerequisites following this instructions:
https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.vmware

And I still see this error. Running same code, against same ESXi hosts on Centos and Ansible 2.9.27 works without any issues.

I tried to find solution online but not much and I already spent 2 days troubleshooting that.

I'd appreciate any insights or help.
Thanks